# trackpad's double tab function contradictions?

Tags: trackpad

I always turn on `tap to click` because I feel that is easier to use trackpad. Then I find one inconvenience of it.

I like double-click to zoom feature in window title

[image: zoom]

But I also like [double-tab to drag](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-pointer-control-settings-accessibility-unac899/mac)

[image: drag]

So if I turn them both on, double tap/click always zoom instead of dragging.

Actually the apple document just says "Double-tap an item, then drag it without lifting your finger after the second tap..." it does not say I have to double-tap on the window title, but through my use I find double-tap on the window title seems to the only place to let me drag the window, double-tap at other place won't work.

So in order to drag effectively I now turn off the double-click to zoom.

Is there anyway to have them both ?

Of course one way to have drag/zoom both is to use three finger drag. But one of reasons I ask my question is why apple ignores such "obvious" contradiction. Do I miss something here?

Comment: I use both (without drag lock though) and never ran into the issue you describe.  If I leave the finger on the trackpad after the second tap, it does not zoom.  If I lift the finger after the second tap, it zooms.

Comment: For double tap not to room, the key point is to **leave the finger on trackpad**, but to me it is a hard gesture, after second tap I always lift my finger (unintentionally), so it zooms. And after trying many times I just resort to three finger to drag.